# Open device using filepath

Tags: c, linux, module, device

I have created a new device called `New_Rule_Table_Device`.

The folder `/sys/class/New_Rule_Table_Class/New_Rule_Table_Class_New_Rule_Table_Device` is said to be a directory (and therefore cannot be written to). What is the correct file path for writing to this device?

Here is the device code:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Query Man");
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

                            // Length of 'test_String'
char* buffer_index;                         // The moving index of the original buffer
static int major_number;                    // Major of the char device
static struct class* sysfs_class = NULL;    // The device's class
static struct device* sysfs_device = NULL;  // The device's name

static char device_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
struct semaphore sem;


/* inode refers to the actual file on disk*/
static int rule_table_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
        if (down_interruptible(&sem) != 0) {
                printk(KERN_ALERT "New_Rule_Table : the device has been opened by some \
                                        other device, unable to open lock\n");
                return -1;
        }
        //buff_rptr = buff_wptr = device_buffer;
        printk(KERN_INFO "New_Rule_Table : device opened succesfully\n");
        return 0;
}

static ssize_t rule_table_read(struct file *fp, char *buff, size_t length, loff_t *ppos)
{
        int maxbytes;           /* maximum bytes that can be read from ppos to BUFFER_SIZE*/
        int bytes_to_read;      /* gives the number of bytes to read*/
        int bytes_read;         /* number of bytes actually read*/
        maxbytes = BUFFER_SIZE - *ppos;
        if (maxbytes > length)
                bytes_to_read = length;
        else
                bytes_to_read = maxbytes;
        if (bytes_to_read == 0)
                printk(KERN_INFO "New_Rule_Table : Reached the end of the device\n");

        bytes_read = bytes_to_read - copy_to_user(buff, device_buffer + *ppos, bytes_to_read);
        printk(KERN_INFO "New_Rule_Table : device has been read %d\n", bytes_read);

        *ppos += bytes_read;
        printk(KERN_INFO "New_Rule_Table : device has been read\n");

        return bytes_read;
}

static ssize_t rule_table_write(struct file *fp, const char *buff, size_t length, loff_t *ppos)
{
        int maxbytes;           /* maximum bytes that can be read from ppos to BUFFER_SIZE*/
        int bytes_to_write;     /* gives the number of bytes to write*/
        int bytes_writen;       /* number of bytes actually writen*/
        maxbytes = BUFFER_SIZE - *ppos;
        if (maxbytes > length)
                bytes_to_write = length;
        else
                bytes_to_write = maxbytes;

        bytes_writen = bytes_to_write - copy_from_user(device_buffer + *ppos, buff, bytes_to_write);
        printk(KERN_INFO "charDev : device has been written %d\n", bytes_writen);
        *ppos += bytes_writen;
        printk(KERN_INFO "charDev : device has been written\n");
        return bytes_writen;
}

static struct file_operations fops = { // Our 'file_operations' struct with declerations on our functions
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .read = rule_table_read,
        .write = rule_table_write,
    .open = rule_table_open
};

static int __init rule_table_init(void) {
    major_number = register_chrdev(0, "New_Rule_Table_Device", &fops);\
    
    if (major_number < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    sysfs_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "New_Rule_Table_Class");
    
    if (IS_ERR(sysfs_class)) {
        unregister_chrdev(major_number, "New_Rule_Table_Device");
        return -1;
    }

    sysfs_device = device_create(sysfs_class, NULL, MKDEV(major_number, 0), NULL, "New_Rule_Table_Class" "_" "New_Rule_Table_Device");  

    if (IS_ERR(sysfs_device)) {
        class_destroy(sysfs_class);
        unregister_chrdev(major_number, "New_Rule_Table_Device");
        return -1;
    }   

    return 0;
}

static void __exit rule_table_exit(void) {
    device_destroy(sysfs_class, MKDEV(major_number, 0));
    class_destroy(sysfs_class);
    unregister_chrdev(major_number, "New_Rule_Table_Device");
}


module_init(rule_table_init);
module_exit(rule_table_exit);
```

EDIT:
Here is the directory tree for the folder:
[image: dir_tree]

If you could help me, that would be appriciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If `New_Rule_Table_Class_New_Rule_Table_Device` is a directory and `New_Rule_Table_Device` is inside of that directory, then I assume that

```
/sys/class/New_Rule_Table_Class/New_Rule_Table_Class_New_Rule_Table_Device/New_Rule_Table_Device
```

would be the correct file path.

Comment: There's no such directory. I'm adding a photo of the directory tree in a post edit, maybe that will clarify.